# List of Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

What is the syntax for making a List of arrays in Java?

I have tried the following:

```
List<int[]> A = new List<int[]>();
```

and a lot of other things.

I need to be able to reorder the int arrays, but the elements of the int arrays need not to be changed. If this is not possible, why?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't instantiate a `List`, as it's an interface. Do you want list of arrays, or are you fine with list of lists?

Comment: I am doing LinkedLists of LinkedLists in lieu of a solution using int[]'s. You are right about not instantiating Lists though, I overlooked that when I posted. Sorry.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Firstly, you can't do `new List();` it is an interface.

To make a list of int Arrays, do something like this :

```
List<int[]> myList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

**P.S.** As per the comment, package for List is `java.util.List` and for ArrayList `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: The compiler gives me this:  The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <int[]>

Comment: @Chet: You've probably got the wrong import then - you should be using `java.util.List`, which certainly *is* generic.

Comment: @Chet you will need to import java.util.List; as well as java.util.ArrayList; for running the code I have written here.

Comment: Damn. Good call. I had awt.List. Seems to work so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

```
List<Integer[]> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
```

Use the object instead of the primitive, unless this is before Java 1.5 as it handles the autoboxing automatically.

As far as the sorting goes:

```
Collections.sort(integerList); //Sort the entire List
```

and for each array (probably what you want)

```
for(Integer[] currentArray : integerList)  
{  
    Arrays.sort(currentArray);  
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `Integer[]` here instead of `int[]`. You can't use primitive types as type arguments, but you can use *arrays* of primitive types.

Comment: In this simple example sure I would agree.  In an ideal world the function would take this: `Collection<Number[]>` and then retrieve values as need be.

Comment: I don't think we have *nearly* enough information for you to make that judgement, to be honest.

Answer (score 6):

List is an interface, not a class. You have to choose what kind of list. In most cases an ArrayList is chosen.

```
List a = new ArrayList();
```

You've mentioned that you want to store an int array in it, so you can specify the type that a list contains.

```
List<int[]> a = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

While you can have a collection (such as a list) of "int[]", you cannot have a collection of "int". This is because arrays are objects, but an "int" is a primitive.