# How memory allocations form in heap when we create a list of arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays, memory

I wonder how the memory allocation forms by JVM when the code below executes. What happens to memory at compile time, what happens at execution time , etc.(would be nice if your answer is with reference to java memory model or possibly something visual)
Thank you in advance

PS. This question is not about [list of arrays in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321956/list-of-arrays-in-java)

```
    List<int[]> arList = new ArrayList<>();

    arList.add(new int[]{1,2});
    arList.add(new int[]{1,2,3,4});

    int n = (int)Math.random()*10;
    int [] a = new int[n];
    arList.add(a);
```

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is "implementation defined". I could be wrong though.

Comment: @EmilyL. what do you mean?

Comment: Every time you create an object, the JVM will allocated enough memory for it. And remember that arrays are objects too.

Comment: I mean that I believe the way the memory is allocated depends on what JVM you use and a general answer is not available. I might have misunderstood your question. Can you clarify please?

Comment: @EmilyL. i meant with reference to java memory model. something visual

Comment: The Java memory model makes no specification of what happens here. It's entirely up to the implementation. Generally, in garbage-collected languages like Java, the answer to memory allocation-related questions is "don't care" unless you're microoptimizing.

Comment: The easiest way to check is to compile the code and examine the class file, that way you can see what goes in the constant pool and what doesn't.

Comment: Obviously, each int array is an object, and the ArrayList is an object, but how many objects are created internal to ArrayList is "implementation defined".

Comment: The java memory model is not about how memory is allocated (although the name might indicate that). The memory model defines the semantics of a java program when multiple threads are used. So it is unclear what you mean with "reference to the java memory model".

Comment: But definitely nothing is allocated at compile time in the traditional sense, even objects that are in the constant pool will only be allocated at class loading time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArrayList and all 3 int arrays get created in the heap in the (more or less) normal fashion (at least so long as the JITC doesn't do stack allocation -- which it would never do for a non-looping `main` method).

```
import java.util.*;
public class IntArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<int[]> arList = new ArrayList<>();

        arList.add(new int[]{1,2});
        arList.add(new int[]{1,2,3,4});

        int n = (int)Math.random()*10;
        int [] a = new int[n];
        arList.add(a);
    }
}
```

The disassembly:

```
C:\JavaTools>javap -c IntArrays.class
Compiled from "IntArrays.java"
public class IntArrays {
  public IntArrays();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":
()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/util/ArrayList
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init
>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_1
       9: iconst_2
      10: newarray       int  <<< Create the first array
      12: dup
      13: iconst_0
      14: iconst_1
      15: iastore
      16: dup
      17: iconst_1
      18: iconst_2
      19: iastore
      20: invokeinterface #4,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.ad
d:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      25: pop
      26: aload_1
      27: iconst_4
      28: newarray       int  <<< Create the second array
      30: dup
      31: iconst_0
      32: iconst_1
      33: iastore
      34: dup
      35: iconst_1
      36: iconst_2
      37: iastore
      38: dup
      39: iconst_2
      40: iconst_3
      41: iastore
      42: dup
      43: iconst_3
      44: iconst_4
      45: iastore
      46: invokeinterface #4,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.ad
d:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      51: pop
      52: invokestatic  #5                  // Method java/lang/Math.random:()D
      55: d2i
      56: bipush        10
      58: imul
      59: istore_2
      60: iload_2
      61: newarray       int  <<< Create the 3rd array
      63: astore_3
      64: aload_1
      65: aload_3
      66: invokeinterface #4,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.ad
d:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      71: pop
      72: return
}
```

What's unknown is how many objects are created internal to the ArrayList.  In the simplest case there would be one Object array (this is what I see in the copy of JDK 6 source I have), but there's nothing to prevent an implementation from using some sort of linked list were each element is a separate object, or some other scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add *"something visual"*. That's what I got taught in my JCP preparation class a while ago on a more abstract level. (Well, not *exactly* that. But ...)

```
runtime stack
+---+
| a | --------------------------------------+
+---+                                       |
+---+                                       |
| n |                                       |
+---+                                       |
+--------+                                  |
| arList | --+                              |
+--------+   |                              |
             |                              |
             |       runtime heap           |
             v                              |
       +-----------+     +-------+          |
       | ArrayList | --> | 1 | 2 |          |
       +-----------+     +-------+          |
          |    |       +---------------+    |
          |    +-----> | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |    |
          |            +---------------+    v
          |                               +---+-...
          +-----------------------------> | 0 | {n times}
                                          +---+-...
```

I think that's the least common denominator before it becomes implementation-specific.