# Is it possible to make a List of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have 3 arrays, 2 arrays of the type int, and one array of the type String.

My question is, is it possible to make a List that contains those 3 arrays?

I want to be able to do something like this: `myList.get(0)` which should give me the first array in the List.

Comment: Have you tried? Also it's probably better to just create a separate class to hold them

Comment: It is possible. However, it's not possible to have a list containing multiple types. The hack is to create all `Object` arrays and store your values, but if you need this kind of hack you should probably rethink about your approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of Arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321956/list-of-arrays-in-java)

Comment: I agree with @BackSlash, I would recommend rethinking your approach to your problem.

Comment: Yes, I would highly recommend rethinking this. The answer provided by davidxxx is the best if you're going to do it this way, but you remove type checking and introduce unsafe casting, which all static code analysis tools will yell at you about, and you could get strange runtime errors down the road when things change. It is not recommended at all. Is there a reason you would like to do this as a list?

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: If you want to group several data, then always consider creating a container class. Then you only need to create a `List<Data>` over this container class.

Comment: As a broad guideline it's best not to mix generics and arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is possible but which value to add arrays of different types in a List ?
You will have to declare a `List<Object>` or `List<Object[]>`. So  you lose the benefit of type safety as you have to cast the array or the array elements to manipulate other things as `Object` variables.

For example :

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new String[5]);
list.add(new Integer[5]);
Object[] objects = list.get(0);
```

You is stuck with an `Object[]`.

To manipulate a more specific type you will have to perform downcast :

```
String[] objects = (String[]) list.get(0);
```

This will work but you can make an error such as :

```
Integer[] objects = (Integer[]) list.get(0);
```

And you would have the information only as an exception at runtime.

Note that using the `instanceof` operator before downcasting the array will not prevent malfunctioning of the program.

For example this will not rise a `ClassCastException` as the conditional statement will be evaluated to `false` :

```
if (list.get(0) instanceof Integer[]){
    Integer[] objects = (Integer[]) list.get(0);
    ...
}
```

But as consequence, it will never execute the processing. It is in a some way even worse as the issue could be not visible for the client.

And using a reversed logic will throw an exception as the initial code if the client uses incorrectly the list but is finally more verbose :

```
if (!(list.get(0) instanceof Integer[])){
    ... // throw exception
}

Integer[] objects = (Integer[]) list.get(0);
```

So definitely, you should forget the idea to add these arrays in a List.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was trying to make a list of those 3 arrays to write it to a binary file, and read from it later on. Probably better to just make a method with 3 parameters for each array.

Comment: Indeed, its makes things clearer. Now as alternative you could also create a custom class that declares the 3 arrays as fields and provide getters for them.