# How can I make an array of my arrays in Java? (WITHOUT ArrayLists)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a few multidimensional arrays of type char[][].
Eg..

```
char[][] ARRAY_1 = {
    {'.','#'},
    {'$','@'}
}
char[][] ARRAY_2 = {
    {'.','#'},
    {'$','@'}
}
```

And I want to make an array or list of some sort such as

```
ARRAY = {ARRAY_1,ARRAY_2,...}
```

so I'll be able to put in ARRAY[1] (or something similar) and have it return the entire char[][] ARRAY_1

I am very new to programming with Java so I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

Edit: I've just found out I'm not allowed to use ArrayLists.

Comment: Stackoverflow previous question-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321956/list-of-arrays-in-java

Comment: *"And I want to make an array or list of some sort  ..."*  -  Please be clear about what you want.  Arrays and lists are different, and there are many ways to create them so the answer will depend on what you want.

Comment: mm if you are at java 9 `List.of(ARRAY_1,ARRAY_2);`

Comment: @soorapadman 9 or 10, haha!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct answer: use `ArrayList<char[][]>` or `char[][][]`.

Basically, you create an ArrayList that holds your 2 dimensional arrays or a 3 dimensional array of chars.

```
List<char[][]> array = new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```
char[][][] array = char[length][][];
```

To add the arrays, you just use the following:

```
array.add(arrayOne); //for an ArrayList
array.add(arrayTwo);
```

or

```
array[0] = arrayOne; //for an array
array[1] = arrayTwo;
```

To get the arrays, you just use the following (where the number is the index):

```
array.get(0); //for an ArrayList
array.get(1);
```

or

```
array[0]; //for an array
array[1];
```

Check out the [ArrayList javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for more information.

(edit: variable changed to match naming conventions)

Comment: I thought you can't use primitive types in java generics? Shouldn't it be Character[][] instead of char[][], or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you explain the char[][][] method? I've tried using it but I'm having trouble calling the array later on.

Comment: @MarDev in Java, arrays are treated as objects, and, therefore, no wrapper class is necessary.

Comment: @MarDev `char[][]` is actually an object which contains a sequence of `char`s (or in this case a sequence of a sequence of `char`s, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<char[][]> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(ARRAY_1);
list.add(ARRAY_2);
```

Or

```
char[][][] ARRAY = new char[length][][];
ARRAY[0] = ARRAY_1;
ARRAY[1] = ARRAY_2;
```

Or

```
char[][][] ARRAY = new char[][][]{ARRAY_1, ARRAY_2};
```

Further reading:

- [ArrayLists in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-in-java/)

Answer (score 1):

So ... if you are not allowed to use lists ... this is one way to make an array of existing arrays.

```
 char[][][] ARRAY = new char[][][]{ARRAY_1, ARRAY_2};
```

Insight #1: an N-dimension array in Java is an array of N-1 dimension arrays (assuming N > 1).

Insight #2: arrays are indexed from zero.

---

> How would I call the arrays individually again later on?

1. You still have the names of the original arrays ... in your example.
2. Base on insight #1":

   ```
   char[][] ARRAY_1_AGAIN = ARRAYS[0];
   System.out.println(ARRAY_1 == ARRAY_1_AGAIN);  // prints true
   ```

   Since `ARRAY_1` is the first subarray of `ARRAY` (as per the previous example), we need to use `ARRAYS[0]` (not `ARRAYS[0]`) to access it.

Comment: How would I call the arrays individually again later on?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Jagged Array...

Also try this

```
char[][] array = new char[5][];

array[0] = array1;
array[1] = array2;
```

Regards