# How to create a List of arrays using java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a arrayList with values `{a,b,a,c,d,b,a}`
I want to make a comparison of each element in the list and insert the `pair` of `common indexes` into a `List of array` or something using java

example output: [[0,2,6], [1,4]]
explanation: `a` is at indexes `0,2,6` and `b` is at indexes `1,4`
So far I have this:

```
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        letter.add("a");
        letter.add("b");
        letter.add("c");
        letter.add("b");
        letter.add("a");

         for (int i = 0; i < letter.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < letter.size(); j++) {
                if (letters.get(i).equals(letters.get(j)) && i != j) {
                    hashMap.put(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(hashMap); //o/p: {0=4, 1=3, 3=1}
        List<int[]> myList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        Iterator entries = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
            Integer key = (Integer)entry.getKey();
            Integer value = (Integer)entry.getValue();
            myList.add(new int[] {key,hashMap.get(key)});
        }
        System.out.println(myList.toString()); 
        //O/P: [[I@380fb434, [I@668bc3d5, [I@3cda1055]
```

**UPDATE:**
the idea was to get [[0,4],[1,3],[3,1]] as elements in `myList` but I am not able to get that. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Based on the above array of indexes, I want to compare the elements in a different `List` `B` and `C` at those indexes - meaning compare elements at indexes `0,2,6` in `List B and C` and check if all three elements are equal. Same for elements at index `1,4`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8321984/10747672

Comment: use Comparator its in built in java, Kinldy have a look

Comment: You make a new ArrayList like List<int[]> bList = new ArrayList<int[]>();

Comment: @AdanVivero I updated the questions. Please check and Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `Map` the way you used to check all indexes of String. You can try with `ArrayList` as below,

```
import java.util.*;

public class ListCharIndexes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> letter = Arrays.asList("a","b","a","c","d","b","a");
       //letter= Arrays.asList("a","b","c","b","a");
        List<List<Integer>> result=new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> result1=new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < letter.size(); i++) {
            if(result1.add(letter.get(i))){ //skip String if it is already processed
                List<Integer> indexes=indexOfAll(letter.get(i), letter);
                if(indexes.size()>1)     //add only pairs
                    result.add(indexes);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    static List<Integer> indexOfAll(String obj, List<String> list) {
        final List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            if (obj.equals(list.get(i))) 
                indexList.add(i);
        return indexList;
    }
}
```

O/P:

> [[0, 2, 6], [1, 5]]

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you:

```
    ArrayList<int[]> arrayList =new ArrayList<>();
    int[] arrayItem={0,2,6};
    int[] arrayItem2={1,4};
    arrayList.add(arrayItem);
    arrayList.add(arrayItem2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Homework done, check this:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        List<String> letter = new ArrayList<String>();
        letter.add("a");
        letter.add("b");
        letter.add("c");
        letter.add("b");
        letter.add("a");

        for (int i = 0; i < letter.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < letter.size(); j++) {
                if (letter.get(i).equals(letter.get(j)) && i != j) {
                    hashMap.put(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(hashMap); //o/p: {0=4, 1=3, 3=1}
        List<int[]> myList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        Iterator entries = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
            Integer key = (Integer)entry.getKey();
            Integer value = (Integer)entry.getValue();
            int[] intValues = new int[2];
            intValues[0] = key;
            intValues[1] = value;
            myList.add(intValues);
        }

        String toPrint = new String();
        toPrint = toPrint.concat("[");
        for(int k = 0; k < myList.size(); k++) {
            toPrint = toPrint.concat("[");
            for(int l = 0; l < myList.get(k).length; l++) {
                toPrint = toPrint.concat(String.valueOf(myList.get(k)[l]));
                if(l != (myList.get(k).length-1)){
                    toPrint = toPrint.concat(",");
                }
            }
            toPrint = toPrint.concat("]");
        }
        toPrint = toPrint.concat("]");

        System.out.println(toPrint);
        //[[0,4][1,3][3,1]]
    }
}
```

If all you needed to do was print the values on the sceen this code will work for you.

Comment: I updated the questions. Please check and Thanks for the response