# How to initialize list of arrays of strings in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list

My code so far:

```
final String[] SOME_COMBINATION = new String[] {
    "strA",
    // just an example
    ("--(:" + 4 + "--B")};
final List<String[]> MY_LIST_OF_ARRAYS = List.of( // error here
    SOME_COMBINATION
);
```

I am getting an error (using Eclipse) for the line in which the list is created:

```
#### Type mismatch: cannot convert from List\<String\> to List<String[]>
```

But `SOME_COMBINATION` is an array of strings here. What am I doing wrong?

Are `List`s of Arrays impossible? (It seems like you can, [in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8321984/2092322).)

Comment: `List.<String[]>of(SOME_COMBINATION)` should work. Otherwise it will infer the desired type of the List to be `String` as suggested by the error message.

Comment: To be clear: the signature of `List#of` here is `<R> List<R> of(R... elems) {...}`. The varargs for the passed-in type means it is equivalent to `of(R[] elems)`, so by passing the array it interprets `R` to be `String`. The solution with the type witness [is noted in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)).

Comment: Note that `SOME_COMBINATION` is not a constant; and the elements of `MY_LIST_OF_ARRAYS` are not constants either. You would be better off using `List<List<String>>` directly, using an immutable list to hold immutable lists.

Answer (score -1):

To make a list of String Arrays, do something like this :

```java
List<String[]> myList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

As per the comment, package for `List` is `java.util.List` and for `ArrayList` it is `java.util.ArrayList`.